# Can someone look at these bugs in VS Code on mac OS X launch.json isn't working

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PySpark",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "osx": {
                "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
            },
            "windows": {
                "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit.cmd"
            },
            "linux": {
                "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
            },
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": null,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "External Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": null,
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "fully qualified path fo 'flask' executable. Generally located along with python interpreter",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/quickstart/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Flask (old)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/run.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [],
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/console.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ],
            "env": null,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: picture of VS trying to run my python]

I am completely new to coding and just want to be able to run the code I am practicing but the launch.json file isn't working you can see all the bugs in the picture.  Someone please help me get to the point where I can run the code I have written and if you could tell me exactly what the launch.json file does as well.

Comment: Post your code and error messages as plain text. Images are not as readable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The code is just the code that comes up automatically when I create a python file in VS Code and go to the debugger and choose python as my configuration.

The problems start like this.
'env.', 'config.' and 'command.' are deprecated, use 'env:', 'config:' and 'command:' instead.  (lines 9 and 27.)
Line nine is as follows:
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",

Comment: It doesn't matter where the code came from—please [edit] your question and then copy and paste the code into it. Do the same with the error messages.

Comment: The text that you have posted is not python code. It is a json format text. You cannot run this as a python file. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well I am trying to run some python that I wrote in VS code but when I attempt to run it VS code adds this launch.json file and it throws all kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The file that appears to be automatically generated is a debugging configuration file that tells VSCode how to launch the program and what to do once it's launched.

The deprecation errors mostly require minor syntactical changes. This is mine for reference

```html
{
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/paster",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "args": [
                "serve",
                "/etc/ckan/default/development.ini"
            ],
            "exceptionHandling": {
                "ignore": ["ImportError"]
            }
        },
```